# Self-signed certificates in Electron

Tags: node.js, ssl, electron, certificate, self-signed

I'm trying to setup a project which uses APIs on a custom local domain (Local DNS server redirecting a custom tld to localhost). On my computer I'm having a nginx reverse-proxy with a mkcert certificate that is loaded and working in Firefox, Chrome and Curl (Certificate is installed and working). I'm running archlinux, if this is related.

When I try to use the electron app, I'm getting the message "self signed certificate in certificate chain".

Any way to fix this issue ? I've already tried to disable ssl verification with the nodejs' env var and used the [syswidecas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/syswide-cas) npm package but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a problem with Node.js, it's a problem with the Chromium embedded in Electron. To actually trust *every* certificate Chromium rejects, you can use code along the lines of the following example from the [Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-certificate-error):

```js
// in your main process, having Electron's `app` imported
app.on ("certificate-error", (event, webContents, url, error, cert, callback) => {
    // Do some verification based on the URL to not allow potentially malicious certs:
    if (url.startsWith ("https://yourdomain.tld")) {
        // Hint: For more security, you may actually perform some checks against
        // the passed certificate (parameter "cert") right here
        
        event.preventDefault (); // Stop Chromium from rejecting the certificate
        callback (true);         // Trust this certificate
    } else callback (false);     // Let Chromium do its thing
});
```

Comment: I've already saw this code somewhere, unfortunately according to the debugger it is never triggered and result in the same error. Even without the domain check...

Comment: Huh? That's strange... You can also try to use this event on the `BrowserWindow`'s `WebContents`; don't quote me on this, but I believe it should work there. See the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-certificate-error), but usage is really the same (simply swap `app` with `window.webContents`).

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to set a custom certificate verification proc. You can do this by calling the following function:

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const win = new BrowserWindow()

win.webContents.session.setCertificateVerifyProc((request, callback) => {
  const { hostname } = request
  if (hostname === 'example.com') { //this is blind trust, however you should use the certificate, valdiatedcertifcate, verificationresult as your verification point to call callback
    callback(0); //this means trust this domain
  } else {
    callback(-3); //use chromium's verification result
  }
})
```

For more details read this:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/session#sessetcertificateverifyprocproc