# Import self signed certificate to Electron App

Tags: node.js, ssl, electron

I have an electron app that allows users to have multiple instances of a web service. Ive setup this web service so that it will only allow HTTPS calls, and it uses a self signed certificate. The user then, from the electron app, makes a request for example`POST https://MY.SERVER.IP/myendpoint` the problem is that electron is rejecting this requests with an `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

I know I can disable the certificates errors by using the following callback

```
app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
  // On certificate error we disable default behaviour (stop loading the page)
  // and we then say "it is all fine - true" to the callback

  event.preventDefault();
  callback(true);
});*/
```

But my guess is that its probably not a very good idea from a security standpoint.

Another solution ive seen proposed for this problem is stated in this question: [Self-signed certificates in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923644/self-signed-certificates-in-electron)

Ill put here the relevant part:

```
// in your main process, having Electron's `app` imported
app.on ("certificate-error", (event, webContents, url, error, cert, callback) => {
    // Do some verification based on the URL to not allow potentially malicious certs:
    if (url.startsWith ("https://yourdomain.tld")) {
        // Hint: For more security, you may actually perform some checks against
        // the passed certificate (parameter "cert") right here
        
        event.preventDefault (); // Stop Chromium from rejecting the certificate
        callback (true);         // Trust this certificate
    } else callback (false);     // Let Chromium do its thing
});
```

The problem here is that the request im making doesnt have a domain name, im calling directly a servers IP address. And I dont know all the allowed IPs when the electron app is started.

My guess is that the solution comes using the function `app.importCertificate` ([See docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appimportcertificateoptions-callback-linux)), but I havent been able to get it to work. This is the steps Ive taken:

1. Generate a self signed certificate `openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey myKey.pem -in cert.pem`
2. Load this certificate in the server. Export this certificate in p12 format `openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey myKey.pem -out myfile.p12`
3. Try to load this certificate in the electron app

```
app.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log('IMPORT CERTIFICATE')
  app.importCertificate({
    certificate: '/path/myfile.p12',
    password: 'MYPASSWORD'
  }, (result) => {
    if (result == 0) {
      console.log('IMPORTED')
    }
    console.log(result)
  });
  
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installExtension(VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
    }
  }
  createWindow();

})
```

I can see in the terminal that the certificate is imported correctly, but when i make a request a still get an `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error.

Comment: Usually, to resolve the error complaining about an invalid certification authority, you would generate not only the server's certificate, but also a (root) CA certificate which will be used to sign the server's certificate. With Chromium, you then only need to import the CA's certificate and I guess it's the same for Electron. Please give [this how-to from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/self-signed-certificates) a try and let me know if that resolved the problem so I can put that into a comprehensive answer.